# ElasticSearch Percolate queries with arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of blacklisted words (5k-10k words) for different users and a movie title I need to search for blacklist words.

I want to know if the movie title contains any blacklisted word of a specific user, so gave a chance to percolate queries explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html).

Created the mapping:

```
PUT /blacklist
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "words": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now index `user id=1`'s blacklist:

```
PUT /blacklist/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "words": ["Star", "Wars", "Trek"]
    }
  }
}
```

And now trying to search `A Journey of some guys on a Star Trek ship` contains any blacklisted word for the user (the answer is, yes).

```
GET /blacklist/_search
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "words": "A Journey of some guys on a Star Trek ship"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but unfortunately, it's not hitting any document.

Searching on the index is also not working.

```
GET /blacklist/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "words": ["Star", "Wars", "Trek"]
    }
  }
}
// No hit
```

And this is the document stored:

```
GET blacklist/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
{
        "_index" : "blacklist",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "query" : {
            "terms" : {
              "words" : [
                "Star", "Wars", "Trek"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

It looks like I couldn't make perculator queries to work with arrays. Can you guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the nature of `terms` queries.

`terms` are not full text queries which means they are not analyzed.

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "words": ["Star", "Wars", "Trek"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here you have all the words with mixed cases. So it will be stored as it is. [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/term-level-queries.html)

But your data `words` is of type text which means

`A Journey of some guys on a Star Trek ship` will be tokenized. Here each word is tokenized using default `standard tokenizer` which includes `lowercase filter`. So `Star` will be stored as `star`.

Hence `Star` is not matching with search term `star`.

To make it work, use below

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "words": ["star", "wars", "trek"] //lowercase
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, thank you. Working great. I also need to know which blacklisted word(s) exist in the movie title. Are there any way to know it? Thanks